# If I use Process to start Explorer, will it open on my user's system?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used the code below to open Explorer in my Web Forms application:

```
String path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "Explorer.exe");
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
p.Start();
```

And it opens Explorer on my computer.

Does it open Explorer on the server or on the client?

Comment: Why not make a virtual machine and host it on your current computer locally, then test it on the virtual one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is executed on the **server** machine. You cannot start a process on the client machine. Not without installing software there. Just imagine what the world would look like, if a random website could start a process on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

It will open on the server. Your `C#` code is a back-end, or server side execution code, hence explorer opens on the server.